# Can't write into mysql database from python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to save an object into a mysql table. I created a database with a table, in this table there's a text column.

my actual code is

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root',        passwd='password',db='database')
x = conn.cursor()
x.execute("""INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES (%s)""", (test,))
```

where test is the object I created parsing from json. After entering this command python shows 1L but when in sql i do

```
select * from table;
```

nothing appears, what is wrong?

Comment: Add a commit command `conn.commit()` to the end of your inputs.  This tells the connection to push the previous commands to the db.

Comment: do i have to add x.commit() under x.execute?

Comment: Yes.  `x.execute(...)` followed by `conn.commit()`.

Comment: it says AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'commit'

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, I meant `conn.commit()`

Comment: thanks! that worked, you can write it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit the changes you make to the data base.  Use:

```
x.execute(...)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try one of two things.  If I have to go with a full script like that, I don't bother using the `conn`... I'll do a subprocess call.

```
# farm_out_to_os.py
cmd = """INSERT INTO table (title) VALUES ({})""".format(test))
subprocess.call("mysql -u{} -p{} < {}".format(uname, pwd, cmd), shell=True)
```

But if you want to do it more programmatically, maybe consider using a full ORM like SQLAlchemy

```
# models.py
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    val = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
```

And the code:

```
# code.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, sessionmaker

engine = create_engine(config.SQLALCHEMY_URL)
session = sqlalchemy.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
newval = models.MyTable(val=5)
session.add(newval)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Depends on what you're trying to do :)